# Solve $i^b = b^i$ for $b$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Solve the equation $i^b = b^i$ for $b$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

This problem appeared on a test.  There may or may not be a specific answer for this problem in which case we would have null set.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Is $b$ complex?

Comment: $i$ can think of one solution.

Comment: And that is supposed to be b = i, i guess?

Comment: @SatishRamanathan oooh... spoiler alert.... :)

Comment: @Blue.  There is a second one (you properly said that $i$ is one). Cheers.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern $b$ can never be real - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=x+iy,\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then$$\begin{align}i^b = b^i&\implies b\,\text{Log}\,i=i\,\text{Log}\,b\\&\implies b\,\text{Log}\,e^{i\pi/2}=i\,\text{Log}\,b\\&\implies\frac\pi2b=\text{Log}\,b\\&\implies\frac\pi2x+i\frac\pi2y=\frac12\ln(x^2+y^2)+i\,\text{Arg}(x+iy)\end{align}$$ Equating real and imaginary parts we have $$\pi x=\ln(x^2+y^2)$$$$\pi y=2\,\text{Arg}(x+iy)$$
In particular, we can write the first equation as $$y=\sqrt{e^{\pi x}-x^2}.$$

### Examples

Let $x=0$. Then $$y=\sqrt{e^0-0}=\pm1$$ so $$b=\pm i.$$ Let $y=0$. Then $$0=2\,\text{Arg}(x)\implies \text{Arg}(x)=0\implies x\in\mathbb{R}$$ but it also has to satisfy $$\pi x=\ln(x^2+0)\implies \ln x=\frac\pi2x$$ which has no real solutions since $x > \ln x$ for all $x > 0$ and $\frac\pi2>1$. Hence $y\neq0$.